# SSIS Package Execution Error 0xC020801C - when running in 32-bit mode

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2019

I've deployed a SSIS package with debugging option Run64BitRuntime = FALSE.  Package runs fine from VS.  When executing the package from SQL Server, I'm selecting the 32-Bit Run Time option but still getting the 0xC020801C error message.

I'm deploying to SQL Server 2019 and the error is from a reference to a .xls Excel file (Office 2007 maybe?).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the *full* error?

Comment: Upload PNTEXP File:Error: Source - PNTEXP$ failed
validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

Comment: Sounds like the file doesn't have the definition the package is expecting.

Comment: Ran through RDP and got these as well:  PNTEXP Upload:Error: SSIS Error Code
DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred.
Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft JET
Database Engine" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description:
"Failure creating file.".

Comment: Upload PNTEXP File:Error: SSIS Error Code
DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNE
CTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to
the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 1"
failed with error code 0xC0202009. There may be error
messages posted before this with more information on why
the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Comment: Upload PNTEXP File:Error: Source - PNTEXP$ failed
validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

Comment: Could it be a security issue?  Meaning access to the SSIS source file?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server did not have access to the source file.  A new share was created on the DB Server, and the SSIS job was successful.